# sendmail 452 4.5.3 Too many recipients

Tags: linux, email, smtp, sendmail

On my server when I try to send mail to more than one recipient I always get a "452 4.5.3 Too many recipients" error. This occurs even when just sending the mail to 2-3 recipients. I use sendmail as my SMTP server on an instance of Amazon Linux.

Command:

```
echo test | mail -s test userA@company.com UserB@company.com
```

/var/log/maillog:

```
sendmail[2413]: starting daemon (8.14.4): SMTP+queueing@01:00:00

sm-msp-queue[2421]: starting daemon (8.14.4): queueing@01:00:00

sendmail[2603]: u1GAHQjS002603: from=ec2-user, size=257, class=0, nrcpts=2, msgid=<201602161017.u1GAHQjS002603@ip>, relay=root@localhost

sendmail[2604]: u1GAHQ1Z002604: from=<ec2-user@ip>, size=580, class=0, nrcpts=2, msgid=<201602161017.u1GAHQjS002603@ip>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]

sendmail[2603]: u1GAHQjS002603: to=userA@company.com,userB@company.com, ctladdr=ec2-user (500/500), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=relay, pri=60257, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (u1GAHQ1Z002604 Message accepted for delivery)

sendmail[2606]: STARTTLS=client, relay=company-com.mail.protection.outlook.com., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384, bits=256/256

sendmail[2606]: u1GAHQ1Z002604: to=<userA@company.com>, ctladdr=<ec2-user@ip> (500/500), delay=00:00:04, xdelay=00:00:03, mailer=esmtp, pri=150580, relay=company-com.mail...ction.outlook.com. [207.46.163.215], **dsn=4.5.3, stat=Deferred: 452 4.5.3 Too many recipients (AS780090)**

sendmail[2606]: u1GAHQ1Z002604: to=<userB@company.com>, ctladdr=<ec2-user@ipl> (500/500), delay=00:00:05, xdelay=00:00:04, mailer=esmtp, pri=150580, relay=company-com.mail...ction.outlook.com. [207.46.163.215], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (<201602161017.u1GAHQjS002603@ipl> [InternalId=341492...PR0801MB1511.namprd08.prod.outlook.com] 6780 bytes in 0.435, 15.205 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery)
```

I've tried adding the following lines in sendmail.mc then issuing the make command and restarting the sendmail service but none of them seem to be doing the trick:

```
define(`confMAX_RCPTS_PER_MESSAGE', `10')dnl
define(`SMTP_MAILER_MAXMSG',`20')
define(`SMTP_MAILER_MAXRCPTS',`50')
```

I have not configured anything else. Am I missing anything? Is this the default behavior for sendmail? The only work around I've figured out to do is to decrease the sendmail retry delay but that is obviously not the preferred solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's not your server or sendmail that's the problem, it's the receiving server saying "Too many recipients."

I hit this problem today, also with domains hosted by mail.protection.outlook.com, after we migrated our production server into AWS over the weekend. Two things to check:

1. Do you have an SPF record (TXT record(s)) on your domain? Is your linux mail server's Elastic IP allowed in the SPF record?
2. Do you have a PTR record (Reverse DNS) for your linux mail server's Elastic IP? Normally you'd ask your Co-Lo to fix this for you. Because you're hosting with AWS you'll need to fill out the "Request to Remove Email Sending Limitations" form as per the following AWS blog post: [Configurable Reverse DNS for Amazon EC2’s Elastic IP Addresses](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/reverse-dns-for-ec2s-elastic-ip-addresses/)

AWS also involves itself in SMTP White Lists with various ISPs so filling out that form is especially important to get your server able to send SMTP mail.